# How to touch everything in a directory including hidden, like directory up `..`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, recursive, touch

This question has parallels to question "[touch all folders in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22291/touch-all-folders-in-a-directory/22298#22298)".

How to `touch` everything in a directory,

- **recursively**
- including hidden entries, like "directory up" `..` and `.`
- without de-referencing symbolic links `touch -h` and
- use a reference file `touch -r <file>` as the the time stamp source

  from within a **shell-script**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `touch` command supports `-h` for *no dereference*:

```
find . -depth -exec touch -h -r "$reference_file" {} +
touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" ..
```

(note that `-h` implies `-c` (to avoid creating the file if it didn't exist with NetBSD/FreeBSD, but not with GNU or busybox `touch` (though with GNU `touch` it wouldn't  create files either and print an error message), so adding `-c` here for increased portability).

Or with with a single `find` command which could reduce the number of `touch` commands being run:

```
find .. . -depth \( ! -name .. -o -prune \) -exec touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" {} +
```

That is, add `..` to the list of files given to `find`, but tell `find` to *prune* it (not descend into it).

For an arbitrary directory (well one whose path doesn't start with `-`:

```
find "$dir/.." "$dir/" \( ! -name .. -o -prune \) \
  -exec touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" {} +
```

(here using `$dir/` instead of `$dir` for the case where `$dir` refers to a symlink to a directory).

With BSD `find`, you can use

```
find -f "$dir/.." -f "$dir/" \( ! -name .. -o -prune \) \
  -exec touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" -- {} +
```

to avoid the problems with `$dir` starting with `-`.

Though you might as well do:

```
(
 cd -P -- "$dir/" &&
   exec find .. . \( ! -name .. -o -prune \) \
     -exec touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" {} +
)
```

(assuming `$reference_file` is not a relative path).

Note that if `$reference_file` is a symlink, with GNU `touch` and with `-h`, the modification time of the symlink will be used (that of the target would be used without `-h`) while with NetBSD ([where `-h` comes from](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/commit/0d89bf83500721729d04e46ccb978fc4564c06ea)) and FreeBSD `touch`, the modification time of the target is used with or without `-h`.

If using `zsh`, you could use its recursive globbing

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- $dir/{.,..,**/*(NDoN)} -- touch -c -h -r $reference_file --
```

(the `oN` for not sorting the list can be omitted, that's just for optimisation).

ksh93 eventually added support for zsh's recursive globbing in 2005, with the `globstar` option.

```
(set -o globstar; FIGNORE=
 command -x touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" -- ~(N)"$dir"/**)
```

Note however that `ksh` will include all `.` and `..` entries here so all directories will be touched several times.

bash eventually copied ksh93's `globstar` in 2009, but was initially /broken/ in that it was following symlinks when descending directories. It was fixed in 4.3 in 2014.

bash doesn't have the equivalent of zsh's `zargs` or `ksh93`'s `command -x` to split command lines so as to avoid the *arg list too long* issues. On a GNU system, you could always use GNU `xargs` for that:

```
xargs -r0a <(
  shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar
  printf '%s\0' "$dir/"{.,..,**}
) touch -c -h -r "$reference_file" --
```

Now, I would probably still use `find` here. Beside the poorer performance, another issue with globs is that errors (like access denied) when traversing the directory tree are silently ignored.

Comment: @ProBackup, see edit

Comment: With arch-linux bash this is the input: `find "/tmp/drp.DSK03fCQTKFZMND/rootfs/.." "/tmp/drp.DSK03fCQTKFZMND/rootfs/" \( ! name .. -o -prune \) -exec touch -h -r /boot/vmlinuz-linux {} +` and its output 
`find: paths must precede expression: name
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: @ProBackup, it should be `-name`, not `name`.

Comment: @PesaThe, see edit.